# Finding the basis of a subspace A whose graph goes through $(4,0)$ and $(5,0)$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Suppose A is the subspace of all polynomials of degree less than or
>   equal to $3$ whose graphs go through the points $(4,0)$ and $(5,0)$.
>   Find a basis of A.

I know that $x-4$ and $x-5$ are usually a good starting point for finding polynomials but I am lost on how to find the basis.

Answer (score 4):

A typical polynomial $p(x) \in A$ is of the form $p(x)=(x-4)(x-5)(ax+b)$, where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. Thus
$$p(x)=a\color{red}{(x-4)(x-5)x}+b\color{blue}{(x-4)(x-5)}.$$
This implies every polynomial in $A$ is expressible as a linear combination of $x(x-4)(x-5)$ and $(x-4)(x-5)$. They are linearly independent as well. So they form a basis.
$$\mathcal{B}_A=\{x(x-4)(x-5), \,\, (x-4)(x-5)\}$$